# Значение с html select в php переменную

Tags: php, html, html-form

есть страница на которой я обновляю информацию блока div (#updatediv) по нажатию клавиши(опустошаю и подгружаю php код с файла допустим update.php). Проблема в том что я хочу установить выпадающий список и брать с него значение в переменную этого файла, допустим выбрал в списке категорию какую либо и нажал сформировать. Список обновился по выбранной категории в select.

Вот код кнопки обновления.

```
<input type="button" value="Сформировать" onclick="$('#updatediv').load('/update.php')">
```

пытался использовать этот код, он дает ровно ничего.

```
<strong>Выберите категорию:</strong>
<form method="post" name="year">
<select name="menu" size="1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">2</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>

<?php
$year = ($_POST['year']); 
echo $year; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы хотите по нажатию на вашу кнопку передать какие-то данные, то нужно дописать передачу этих данных:

```
...
<input ... onclick="$('#updatediv').load('update.php', { 'year': document.forms.year.menu.value })">
...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а как его дальше использовать в файле, я так понимаю он же не присваивается в переменную

Comment: значение попадает в `$_POST['year']`